# Error in Math.factor(c(1L, 3L, 4L, : ‘round’ not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, refactoring, rounding

I always get this error: Error in Math.factor(c(1L, 3L, 4L,  :    ‘round’ not meaningful for factors for the following code:

```
C1<-train_data[,m]
  C2<-as.factor(C1)
  class_values<-C2

  train_data <- train_data[,-m]
  control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=1)
  train_model <-train(train_data,class_values,method='nb',trControl=control)
```

I tried to put: C2=as.factor(as.numeric(as.character(C1)), but not solved.
C1 is numeric data from 1 to 5.

Comment: So did I understand right, you get the error for the second command (`C2<-as.factor(C1)`) ?

Could you post the output of `str(train_data)` or `str(C1)`

Comment: str(train_data)
'data.frame': 269 obs. of  1174 variables:
 $ V2   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V3   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 ...
 $ V4   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

Comment: str(C1)
 int [1:269] 4 2 2 3 2 4 4 3 3 2 .

Comment: C1 is just the last column of Train_Data.

Comment: Does `nb` method allow factors? (in case you still have factors within our 1174 variables training data.frame)

Comment: Actually, naive Bayes Require them as Factors.

Comment: otherwise gives: Error: wrong model type for regression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rounding: you should either do:

```
df <- data.frame(a = factor(c(1.1,2.2,3.3)))
df$b = round(as.numeric(levels(df$a)[df$a]))
```

Or using data.table framework:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, b:= round(as.numeric(levels(a)[a]))]
```

After, we would need to see what is in your functions to know what's wrong...
Hope it helps.

Comment: The Code where I used round:
 
    C1<-train_data[,m]
    class_values<-as.factor(C1)
    train_data <- train_data[,-m]

    control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=1)
    train_model <-train(train_data,class_values,method='nb',trControl=control) 
   
    test_data<- read.table(test_file, sep=",")
    test_data<- test_data[-1,-1]
    m<-length(test_data[1,])
    truth<-test_data[,m]
    test_data<-test_data[,-m]
     predictions <- predict(train_model, test_data)
    prd<-round(predictions,digits=0)

Comment: apparently 'nb' outputs Factors(i.e. predictions) and when using:    prd<-round(predictions,digits=0)    error happens

Comment: Just to be clear the issue appears when you run train? Or do you perform rounding on your own?

Comment: I was using as.factor before train so I thought it generates the error but after tracing I found that round causes it because the output of Bayes is also factor.